# In Azure, To get Load balancer details in to csv file using powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I wrote a powershell script in Azure DevOps pipeline to get Load Balancer details like FrontendIPConfigurationsName,FrontendIPAddress in to csv file. AM getting those details but FrontendIPConfigurationsNames which starts with same name like "ers-A1,ers-B1,ers-C1,ers-D1" are coming in same row. But I want to get them in different rows.Please suggest

```
$excel = @()
LBlist = Get-AZLoadBalancer | Where-Oject {$_.ResourceGroupName -clike '$(grp-wildcard)'} | Select-Object
foreach ($LB in LBlist)
$Array =""| Select-Object ResourceGroupName, FrontendIPConfigurationsName,FrontendIPAddress
$Array.ResourceGroupName =$LB.ResourcegroupName
$Array.FrontendIPConfigurationsName = ($LB.FrontendIpConfigurationsName.name -join ',')
$Array.FrontendIPAddress =($LB.FrontendIpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress -join ',')
}
$excel +=$Array
$excel |Format-Table ResourceGroupName, FrontendIPConfigurationsName,FrontendIPAddress
$excel | Export-Csv -NTI -Path "($Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/LBlist.csv
```

Comment: I suspect you'd get an answer on this faster if you included a shim or mock for `Get-AZLoadBalancer`.

Comment: @derekbaker783 Could you please explain me in detail. Am new to powershell.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful to others if, at the top of your code sample, you defined at function that returned a "canned" object/array of objects that allows others reproduce the issue you're encountering. 

Alternatively, you might consider including an example of what is returned by `Get-AZLoadBalancer` (including the type).

Comment: Also, you have a few syntax errors in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this to get the objects on separate rows.

```bsh
$LBlist = Get-AZLoadBalancer | Where-Object { $_.ResourceGroupName -clike '$(grp-wildcard)' }

$LBlist | Export-Csv -NTI -Path "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/LBlist.csv"
```

Mock for `Get-AZLoadBalancer` (not sure if it's entirely accurate as I've never used Az Powershell)

```bsh
function Get-AZLoadBalancer() {
    $obj = @(
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            ResourceGroupName = '$(grp-wildcard)'
            FrontendIPConfigurationsName = 'ers-A1'
            FrontEndIPAddress = '1.2.3.4'
        },
        [PSCustomObject] @{
            ResourceGroupName = '$(grp-wildcard)'
            FrontendIPConfigurationsName = 'ers-B1'
            FrontEndIPAddress = '1.2.3.5'
        }
    )
    return $obj
}
```